# JQuery DOM appended elements

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I have a code where I can adding next input fields, and after that I use this code to get to array

```
$("#mobiles input").each(function(){
array[$(this).attr("id")] = $(this).val();
});
$("#emails input").each(function(){
array[$(this).attr("id")] = $(this).val();
});
```

The first one ID '`$("#mobiles input")`' works fine. But second doesn't work. Showing undefined...

HTML CODE:

```
<table id='mobiles'>
            <tr>
            <td><?php echo MOBILE; ?> 1</td>
            <td><input style='width: 250px;' type='text' id='mobile1'></td>     
            </tr>
            </table>

<table>
            <tr>
            <td style='width: 50px;'><img src='images/add_client/plus.png' style='cursor: pointer;' id='addMobile'></td>
            <td style='text-align: right; width: 260px;'><img id='deleteMobile' src='images/add_client/del.png' style='cursor: pointer;'></td>
            </tr>
</table>

<table id='emails'>
            <tr>
            <td><?php echo EMAIL; ?> 1</td>
            <td><input type='text' style='width: 250px; margin-left: 9px;' id='email1'></td>        
            </tr>
            </table>

            <table>
            <tr>
            <td style='width: 50px;'><img src='images/add_client/plus.png' style='cursor: pointer;' id='addEmail'></td>
            <td style='text-align: right; width: 260px;'><img id='deleteEmail' src='images/add_client/del.png' style='cursor: pointer;'></td>
            </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Why are you not using the input's id directly? $("#email1")

Comment: Oh I see why. never mind.

Comment: Try using an object instead of an array...

Comment: Must be a separate issue, there is nothing wrong with this code